# How to host Bottle in Pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

I have a simple bottle project (using one template file in the views folder) that runs correctly locally. I read the help files in Pythonanywhere, I tried different ways to edit the WSCI files, but still can't get bottle run correctly. Can someone please show me a minimal example to run a Bottle?

Comment: if you want a minimal example, from pythonanywhere, go to the webapps tab, and create a bottle webapp- that will create a working bottle webapp for you, and you could perhaps change the files from there

Comment: The default example returns a single string, no template files, no static files. Hardly useful for beginners to try first useful Bottle web site. A good example:  

(1) simple template file:  
       <p>Hello from bottle.</p><img src='images/bottleLogo.jpg/>  

(2) set up to send static images.  

Simple yet illustrative. May be bottlepy.org can explain with one such simple example.  

Thanks for the suggestion! I did eventually figured out how to do it.